# How to pass navigation props in React native in Stack Navigation?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-native-navigation

I am new to react native and facing some issues with React Navigation version 5.x

App.js file is below

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import MyDrawer from "./components/MyDrawer";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";

import firebase from "firebase";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./config";
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  };
  logOut = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        >
          {this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MyDrawer} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={LoginScreen} />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

If the user is logged in to firebase it will navigate to MyDrawer.js. It has a custom drawer and the drawer has a log out button.

MyDrawer.js

```
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import Colors from "../Colors";
import ShareListScreen from "../screens/ShareListScreen";
import Inpiration from "../screens/Inspiration";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default class MyDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: this.props,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Share List" component={ShareListScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Inspiration" component={Inpiration} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <View >
        <ImageBackground source={image} >
          <Text>
            Bring
            <Text>Me</Text>
          </Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <ImageBackground source={home} >
        <Text >Home</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
      <ImageBackground source={work} >
        <Text>Workplace</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Log out"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.logOut;
          this.props.navigation.navigate("SignIn"); 
 
  // Once the button pressed I want the user to sign out from firebase and navigate
to the root and set isLoggedIn state to true in App.js. 

        }}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Once the logout button pressed I want the user to sign out from firebase and navigate to the root and set isLoggedIn state to true in App.js. ( Call the log out function in App.js).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it's not best approach to call logout after navigation. You should move your logout code into drawer screen, onPress of logOut button firstly logOut user from firebase then navigate to the root in callback function. to avoid navigation complexity try to use Async-storage . If you want to play with props more often, try react-native Hooks instead of regular classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the initialParams to pass the logout function.

```
 <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MyDrawer} initialParams={{this.logout}}/>
```

This function can be accessed in MyDrawer class as `this.props.routes.params.logout()`

And you dont have to navigate to signIn again as the state change happens you render the 'SignIn' so app will show the signin screen automatically.

Comment: That's okay. But how can I pass the function to CustomDrawerContent.
this.props.routes.params.logout() is not working inside the CustomDraweContent

Comment: try this <CustomDrawerContent {...props} logout={this.props.routes.params.logout} />